# Pop Up Text Field Java

Tags: java, swing, popup, jframe, textfield

I have a button and on click I want it to load a text field (like a pop up). Is this possible?

I've looked into

```
this.setVisible(false);
new className().setVisible(true);
```

But this means I'd need a new JFrame. I'm not against the idea - I'm just asking if there is a better way of doing it. If possible, I want it to load JUST a text field instead of a the frame that is around it.

I've just created JOptionPane as suggested below - But i'm still having problems. The pop up appears, but nothing is included in the box.

When mouse is clicked on class 1:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, MetaData.getTags());
```

class 2 (I'm aware this isn't the best way to throw exceptions. This is only a rough program). Using [metadata extractor](http://www.drewnoakes.com/code/exif/) for those who are interested.

```
public String getTags() {
        try {
            Metadata metadata = ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(jpegFile);

            for (Directory directory : metadata.getDirectories()) {
                for (Tag allTags : directory.getTags()) {
                    System.out.println("MetaData Class: " + allTags);
                }
            }
        } catch (ImageProcessingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MetaData.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MetaData.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return allTags;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get user input with a popup, you may use `JOptionPane.showInputDialog`. It will essentially instantiate a `JDialog` with an input text field and OK/Cancel buttons.

If you don't like this "pre-made" library method, you have to roll your own `JDialog`: make it modular and generic, so that if in the future you need the same tool you won't have to make it from scratch or copy/paste.
Please note that you can have a dialog *without the external frame* (if you are looking for something less intrusive than a window, like a tooltip). See http://www.stupidjavatricks.com/?p=4.

I don't see other options.

Comment: I've read the update, but I just don't get what you are trying to do. Weren't you just trying to get user input from a popup/tooltip?

Comment: Nope. Data is already retrieved but not printed. I wanted this button to create a report of some type. I did try writing it to the document but it came back as "null". This would suggest there's nothing there, but it prints in NetBean output screen fine.